# Spring JPA Hibernate prevent show sql in console log

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I use spring 2.4 and logback.I want to close hibernate show_sql property but it doesnt work

I tried this options

in my hibernate.properties,I set `hibernate.show_sql=false`

in my application.properties

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=false
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
```

Also I tried to set mycontext with setJpaProperties(set Properties ) here but still doesnt effect

I tried this configurations but still doesnt work

18:03:55.842 [Thread-34] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - select my0_.xx as my1_0_,  from mytable my0_

[Thread-32] DEBUG o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Processing attribute `name` : value =

How can I prevent this logs coming

Answer (score 2):

I propose to change the hibernate log level using this configuration

```
logging.level.org.hibernate=INFO
```

Comment: this is work,thanks do you have any comment why show_sql false not enough because of logback implemantation?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think that your logback root log level is DEBUG, isn't it?

Comment: yes,as we understand when root level debug that time show_sql useless